# Which number is bigger: $e^{\sqrt{5}} + e^{\sqrt{7}}$ or $2e^{\sqrt{6}}$?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:(0, + \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x) = e^{\sqrt{x}}$.

Which number is bigger:  $e^{\sqrt{5}} + e^{\sqrt{7}}$ or $2e^{\sqrt{6}}$?

I would like to ask for a hint on how to approach this question, I don't have an idea.

Comment: I would first check if the function $f:x\mapsto e^{\sqrt{x}}$ is convex or concave on the interval $[5,7]$. If either of the two, you can then use [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Comment: It might be worth looking at the sign of the second derivative of $\exp(\sqrt{x})$ when $x>1$

Comment: A nice way is to take the natural log of all these as log function is increasing, you will be able to compare them

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai: but you can't take the natural log of $e^{\sqrt 5}+e^{\sqrt 7}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{\sqrt{x}}$, so the second derivative is:

$$f''(x)=\frac{e^{\sqrt{x}}}{4x^{3/2}}(\sqrt{x}-1)$$
Since $f''(x)>0$ for $x\in (1,\infty)$, it is concave up (convex). So we have

$$\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}>f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)$$

Let $x=5, y=7$

$$\frac{f(5)+f(7)}{2}>f\left(6\right)$$

Comment: Yeah, "concave up" is unusual terminology. Prefer "convex."

Comment: I see, (some) textbook uses concave up/ concave down, instead of convex/concave... @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: Yes, I add this term, thank you @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Hi, please do not answer such questions which shows no effort from the OP

Comment: @Math That’s interesting, I never heard of that terminology so I learned something :)

Answer (score 2):

We have
\begin{align*}
e^{\sqrt{5}} > 2^{\sqrt{5}} > 2^1 \implies \frac{1}{e^\sqrt{5}} < \frac{1}{2} \tag{$*$}\\
e^{\sqrt{7}} > 2^{\sqrt{7}} > 2^1 \implies \frac{1}{e^\sqrt{7}} < \frac{1}{2} \tag{$**$}
\end{align*}
Now because $\ln{x}$ is an increasing function, we can write:
\begin{align*}
\ln(e^{\sqrt{5}} + e^{\sqrt{7}}) &= \ln\left(\frac{e^{\sqrt{5}} + e^{\sqrt{7}}}{e^{\sqrt{5}}e^{\sqrt{7}}}\right) + \ln(e^{\sqrt{5}}) + \ln(e^{\sqrt{7}})\\
&= \ln\left(\frac{1}{e^{\sqrt{5}}} + \frac{1}{e^\sqrt{7}}\right) + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}\\
(*), (**) &< \ln\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right) + \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}\\
&= \sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7}\\
(?) &< 2\sqrt{6}\\
&= \ln(e^{2\sqrt{6}})
\end{align*}
Notice that for $(?)$ we can write:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7} < 2\sqrt{6} &\iff (\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{7})^2 < (2\sqrt{6})^2\\
&\iff 12 + 2\sqrt{35} < 24\\
&\iff \sqrt{35} < 6
\end{align*}